# How can i assign perticular size to datanode in HDFS?

Tags: hdfs

My current datanode size is 128MB which is by default and
         i want to change the size of that because in my project 
        there are lots of text files are going to store in hdfs
         which means size of those files are very less(less than 10M)
         so i want to change the size of block. Give me some useful 
        suggestions and comments. I already tried some tricks but
         it was not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this property into **hdfs-site.xml** file between configuration tag. 
 `67108864 bytes= 64mb`. 
Write **size** as per your requirement in **bytes**.  
`dfs.block.size` `67108864`